# Como mostrar y ocultar diferentes div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, div

Estoy intentando hacer un codigo para que al clicar en diferentes div se muestren y se oculten. Ejemplo:

Tengo 7 divs, al hacer clic en 1 de ellos, los otros 6 se tienen que ocultar. El problema es que no consigo ocultar los 6 div que no deben aparecer.

Tengo el siguiente codigo que no se si es correcto pero me "funciona". Pero claro, me "funciona" solo con 1 div. A partir de aquí, no se como añadir las diferentes combinaciones.

```
function divLogin(){ 

   if(clic==1){

   document.getElementById("abrir").style.height = "auto";
   document.getElementById("cerrar").style.display = "none"; 

   clic = clic + 1;

   } else{

       document.getElementById("abrir").style.display = "none"; 

    clic = 1;

   }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haria asi. Creas un evento onclick donde le pasas el índice del div como argumento. Al llamar al evento con Javascript haces un bucle que pase por todos divs y todos los que no coincidan con el argumento donde has hecho click, se le añade una clase y se le cambia el estilo a esa clase.

```js
 function hideDivs(clickedIndex) {
        const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div-box");
        for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
          if (i !== clickedIndex) {
            divs[i].classList.add("div-hidden");
          }
        }
      }
```

```css
 .div-hidden {
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
      <div class="div-box" onclick="hideDivs(0)">Div 1</div>
      <div class="div-box" onclick="hideDivs(1)">Div 2</div>
      <div class="div-box" onclick="hideDivs(2)">Div 3</div>
      <div class="div-box" onclick="hideDivs(3)">Div 4</div>
      <div class="div-box" onclick="hideDivs(4)">Div 5</div>
      <div class="div-box" onclick="hideDivs(5)">Div 6</div>
      <div class="div-box" onclick="hideDivs(6)">Div 7</div>
    </div>
```